# How can I easily use the gcc compiler for arm for building in a development IDE?

Tags: ide

I would like to replace the non-open lpcxpresso IDE with a free IDE. Any pointers how to do it best? How can I point one of the existing IDEs to use the arm gcc compiler?

Comment: This seems like a very technical question, maybe you should try and ask it at http://stackoverflow.com/ that site is more focused on programming/development. My sense is that most users on this site is Ubuntu end/super-users not programmers in particular. If you do get an answer on stackoverflow.com or another site please answer this question with a link and accept the answer :)

Comment: Well.. I might also ask it there, but I think this site encompasses a wide range of questions and knowledge levels, and I would encourage questions like that in order to bring Ubuntu also forward for such users.

Comment: Development questions that relate specifically to Linux and Ubuntu are perfectly fine for asking here. Stack Overflow is indeed, in my opinion anyway, the best place to go with a programming question, but there's no reason it can't be asked here as well. The goal of this site is to become a one stop shop for questions related to Ubuntu, and as far as the programming interface is concerned, Ubuntu and Linux are on in the same.

Answer (score 5):

I'm by no means an expert on the subject, but hopefully I can point you in the right direction. As far as IDEs go, there is a [GNU ARM plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuarmeclipse/) for the [Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/). It is a  Manged Build Extension that supports a number of GNU ARM Toolchains like CodeSourcery G++ Lite, GNUARM, WinARM, Yagarto, devkitPro.

Outside of an IDE, you could consider running a QEMU ARM image. A discussion on how to setup a QEMU ARM image and to build ARM packages with it can be found here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/BuildArmPackages

Answer (score 1):

The only free Linux choice is to run eclipse/arm-elf-gcc using the makefile project option of this IDE, where you will write your own makefile. The drawbacks are the lack of ready to debug feature, so you will need to use OpenOCD, there is plenty of info on the internet.

As second choice, you could run a CoIDE over wine or virtual machine, and use their own debugger. This IDE only works on Cortex M3 chips, is free, has a open-hardware debug probe and its use is extremely easy.